# Is it Basic64 in the header? "Authorization: Basic pnbuvdipay1p3yrqpuychdyj"

Tags: security, session, authentication

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,    like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36

**Authorization: Basic pnbuvdipay1p3yrqpuychdyj**

Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Authorization is Basic but I can't just decrypt it as Basic 64. What should I do?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side

Comment: I can't find an online resource that I can use to decode it. Do you know where?

Comment: Nope, the string doesn't seem to be following the RFC mentioned in the Wikipedia article

Comment: I copied pasted it from proxy history

Comment: It seems the behaviour is not standardized, so this could be a custom encoding. You'd likely have to look for which product was used on server side. What do you need this for in the first place? (Your proxy should arguably not save this stuff.)

Comment: I get that using Basic Authorization is not safe even if it used under HTTPS, but I can't show POC that this is bad a practice, I can't show bad practice if it not decodable

Comment: I see. I guess they could be using a custom encoding, which may well be as insecure (just a different base, for example) but still takes some knowledge and work to break.